# Speed Up Containstable Query SQL Server 2008 with Paging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

is there a way of speeding up the following containstable query in SQL Server 2008. The database has 600,000 records and the query takes 2 seconds. I need to use the query with paging. Other queries not involving containstable are faster. It seems that a relevance search is expensive. Any way to improve this in SQL Server 2008?

```
WITH RowsTable AS
(
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ct.[RANK] DESC)) AS RowNum, e.* 
    FROM CONTAINSTABLE ([Web.ProductDB], title, 'dell') As ct 
    JOIN [WebCMS.Product] As e ON ct.[KEY] = e.ID
    WHERE (ct.[RANK] > 0)
)
SELECT title,Manufacturer,DescpTop
FROM RowsTable
WHERE (RowNum >= 1) AND (RowNum < 21)
```

Ideally i am wanting performance of less than 1 second. Thanks.

Comment: First of all try to move your JOIN out from CTE.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: Something like this: `WITH RowsTable AS
(
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ct.[RANK] DESC)) AS RowNum, ct.[KEY] 
    FROM CONTAINSTABLE ([Web.ProductDB], title, 'dell') As ct 
    WHERE (ct.[RANK] > 0)
)
SELECT e.title,e.Manufacturer,e.DescpTop
FROM RowsTable AS rt
    JOIN [WebCMS.Product] As e ON rt.[KEY] = e.ID
WHERE (rt.RowNum >= 1) AND (rt.RowNum < 21)`

Comment: thanks but that still takes a couple of seconds